# when crontab job reads BMP180 sensor it returns 0

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, cron, sensors

I have a raspberry PI B+ as a weather station outside. Within the control box I have the PI and a heater (for protection if the temperature should go under 0°C).

I have programmed some functions in PHP and they work fine with the crontab but one.
The file that causes me nightmares should take two temperatures from two sensors and write two files (one log and one instant temperature with some other data).

I use two commands in order to do that:

```
$temp_ex=round(system("checktemp"),1);
$temp_el=round(system("python temp_connectivity.py"),1);
```

the first command runs everytime. With no problems whatsoever.
The second command, which calls:

```
import Adafruit_BMP.BMP085 as BMP085
sensor = BMP085.BMP085()
print '{0:0.2f}'.format(sensor.read_temperature())
```

works only if I run my php file with the terminal. I get the correct temperature.
When the file is used by the crontab I always get 0 (even at 20°C).

Both python and php files have execute rights. I tried both with system() and exec() commands with no luck.

Anyone that can suggest me a way out? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the sensor or the code.
It was the crontab, or the permits spinning around this service.

I have used "crontab -e" in order to create my jobs but that was not good enough. I tried some other ways to call my script but I only managed to get it to work using:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

There was many python scripts that did not work but since they were hidden and not very important I failed to notice them failing.